# how to bypass error in selenium python web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have written the following code for web scraping. the code without the if else loop part works fine, that i intend to do. I have a list of urls which i want to scrape and if in any url the element that doesnt exist, then i have to bypass that url and move on to the next. I achieved bypassing the url that has no element, but my normal scraping then doesnt work in the else loop as it should.
any help guys?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  

urls= [
'http://www.marketsmojo.com/Stocks?StockId=1002687&Exchange=0'
]
f= open("lolly.txt","a+")
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('http://www.marketsmojo.com/Stocks?StockId=565016&Exchange=0')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='step-0']/a/i").click()
for url in urls:
    browser.get(url)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(10,9500);")
    browser.implicitly_wait(2000)
    if browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,' No Shareholding data available ')]"):
        continue
    else:
        add=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnShareholdingDashboardFullDetails')
        SearchButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnShareholdingDashboardFullDetails')
        Hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(add).move_to_element(SearchButton)
        Hover.click().perform()
        browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#allquarters > div > table')
        add1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#AllQuarters')
        SearchButton1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#AllQuarters')
        Hover1 = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(add).move_to_element(SearchButton1)
        Hover1.click().perform()
        data = []
        for tr in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#allquarters > div > table'):
            ths = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
            tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
            if ths: 
                data.append([th.text for th in ths])
            if tds: 
                data.append([td.text for td in tds])
            f.write(str(data))

    
browser.quit()
```

Comment: if it stops without error, that means there is no errors, just it does not works as you think it works.

Comment: post the error you got

Comment: @Arount: there is no error, that's right but the else block doesnt get executed at all.! the url gets clicked and the web page stays forever.

Comment: question is really unclear.

Comment: @GaurangShah sorry about my english part.! hopefully now it should be ok?

Comment: Perhaps its a combo of scrolling to 9500 and waiting 2000 seconds?
Try inserting breakpoints if your ide supports so - or insert print statements to check where your script executes, eg one ofter the scroll, one after the wait and one at the top of your conditions...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble guys, it was just the timeout function that caused the hiccup.!
code is perfectly fine.